# Angular $injector vs inject

Tags: angularjs

I've been using two ways to inject dependencies into unit tests and I wondered what the difference was and if one way is better, as the end result is the same. Both snippets below output the same 'calendarSvc' Service object.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
  console.log(1, $injector.get('calendarSvc'));
}));

beforeEach(inject(function(calendarSvc) {
  console.log(2, calendarSvc);
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, `inject` uses `$injector` to do the job, so it is the same thing at the end.

The advantage of `inject` is that is more visual, easy and less code to write. It works like the normal angular DI, just adding what you need to inject via params.

See it like why normal injection vs `$injector` in normal code. It is much faster to just write a parameter per dependency that having to manual inject all of them.